# Queryselector returning null for an existing element in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am not sure why this line of code is returning an error, but I have spent hours on it and I have yet to understand why. I have a div element in the navigation bar with a module class that does not have any changed property within the CSS file, it is just a block. (I have used a module class that does have properties changed within the CSS file but the error has persisted). I did try it with a regular class and the Queryselector found the element, but in this project, I need to use modules. Can anyone please help me understand why this Queryselector returns null when trying to access the div element?

```js
const Nav = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(document.querySelector('.testing'))
    window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // console.log(document.querySelector('.testing'))
        if(document.querySelector(`.${styles.testing}`).contains(e.target)){
            // is not able to find the element with the className 'testing'
            // irrelevant code here
        } 
    })
}, [])

return (
  <>
    <div className={`${styles.user_interaction_container} ${styles.list}`}>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <img src={search} alt="Search" width="16px" height="16px"></img>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <img src={heart} alt="Liked" width="16px" height="16px"></img>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/">
            <img src={cart} alt="Cart" width="16px" height="16px"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.testing}>
        <img src={menu} alt="Menu" width="20px" height="20px"></img>
    </div>
  </>
)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Code doesn't work but I just wanted to show what it looks like. Here is a screenshot of the issue (All of the other Queryselectors work)

[image]

**What I don't understand is how it is able to find other elements identically called but can't access this specific class??**

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: It's a bit anti-pattern in React to use query selector. Try using a React ref and see if your situation improves.

Comment: `useEffect` DOES run after your render function completes but not necessarily before react has made the changes to the DOM to reflect your render function.

 Your element is not in the DOM when `useEffect` runs. Use a ref or better yet refactor to avoid the ref and the query selector. If you tell us what you're trying to do we may be able to suggest a more react-y way.

Comment: Would I have to style the ref elements within the JS file itself or could I somehow do the style in the CSS and reference some sort of class the ref could use?

Comment: React refs are just a way to access underlying DOMNodes. You are free to style elements however you see fit. What are you trying to do?